# Как оформлять библиотеки?

Tags: javascript, библиотеки

Создал небольшой скрипт, хочу использовать его как библиотеку. Скрипт состоит из функции которая используется в конструкторе объектов (то есть как я понимаю глобальное пространство имен засорено только именем функции).

Как мне реализовать этот скрипт в качестве библиотеки?

Comment: какой вид библиотеки имеется ввиду? скрипт для браузера или nodejs?

Comment: @Grundy Браузер

Comment: тогда посмотри на уже существующие библиотеки типа jquery, lodash, underscore и т.д. Принцип один и тот же - запись в глобальную переменную. Сам скрипт - отдельный файл.

Answer (score -1):

небольшой пример из жизни TypeScript

[typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20namespace%20user%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20fullName%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20user%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20let%20name%20%3D%20''%0D%0A%20%20%20%20export%20let%20surename%20%3D%20''%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(user%2C%20'fullName'%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20user.name%20%2B%20user.surename%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20namespace%20user%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20var%20hiddenVariable%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Anamespace%20user%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20hiddenVariable%20%3D%20''%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(user%2C%20'hiddenVariable'%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20hiddenVariable%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20set%3A%20(_val)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20type%20%3D%20Object.prototype.toString.call(_val)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20('%5Bobject%20String%5D'%20!%3D%3D%20type)%20throw%20new%20TypeError('_val%20is%20not%20String')%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hiddenVariable%20%3D%20_val%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Auser.name%20%3D%20'qwa'%0D%0Auser.surename%20%3D%20'bra'%0D%0Aconsole.log(user.fullName)%0D%0A%0D%0Atry%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20user.hiddenVariable%20%3D%20%5B''%5D%0D%0A%7D%20catch%20(_e)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('error%3A'%2C%20_e.message)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Auser.hiddenVariable%20%3D%20'hidden'%0D%0Aconsole.log(user.hiddenVariable)%0D%0A)

### TypeScript

```
declare namespace user {
    var fullName: string
}
namespace user {
    export let name = ''
    export let surename = ''
    Object.defineProperty(user, 'fullName', {
        get: () => user.name + user.surename
    })
}
declare namespace user {
    var hiddenVariable: string
}
namespace user {
    let hiddenVariable = ''
    Object.defineProperty(user, 'hiddenVariable', {
        get: () => hiddenVariable,
        set: (_val) => {
            let type = Object.prototype.toString.call(_val)
            if ('[object String]' !== type) throw new TypeError('_val is not String')
            hiddenVariable = _val
        }
    })
}

user.name = 'qwa'
user.surename = 'bra'
console.log(user.fullName)

try {
    user.hiddenVariable = ['']
} catch (_e) {
    console.log('error:', _e.message)
}
user.hiddenVariable = 'hidden'
console.log(user.hiddenVariable)
```

### JavaScript

```js
var user;
(function(user) {
  user.name = '';
  user.surename = '';
  Object.defineProperty(user, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
      return user.name + user.surename;
    }
  });
})(user || (user = {}));

var user;
(function(user) {
  var hiddenVariable = '';
  Object.defineProperty(user, 'hiddenVariable', {
    get: function() {
      return hiddenVariable;
    },
    set: function(_val) {
      var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(_val);
      if ('[object String]' !== type)
        throw new TypeError('_val is not String');
      hiddenVariable = _val;
    }
  });
})(user || (user = {}));

user.name = 'qwa';
user.surename = 'bra';
console.log(user.fullName);

try {
  user.hiddenVariable = [''];
} catch (_e) {
  console.log('error:', _e.message);
}

user.hiddenVariable = 'hidden';
console.log(user.hiddenVariable);
```

Answer (score -3):

Вообще лучше всего библиотеку оформлять в виде UMD модуля, так его удобно будет подключить на сайты с разными системами сборки: webpack, browsify, requirejs и т.д. Подробнее: https://github.com/umdjs/umd